# Merge two sorted arrays with recursion without 3nd array

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I'm a computer science student in my first year.
I was given a task in recursion.
I need to write a recursive function that gets two arrays and they are their physical size (non-negative) and sorts the arrays and puts them into the second array in a sorted way without an array set up for help. Presumably the size of the second array is sufficient. I can not write code that works for me, I would love for you to help me.

Comment: Are the arrays sorted? Because in the title you wrote "merge two sorted arrays", but in description you wrote that function should sort arrays.

Comment: "gets two arrays" How? What is the interface for the function? Where can it access them? "they are their physical size" Is unclear. Does the interface provide those sizes?  "Presumably the size of the second array is sufficient. " Good. But then you need three sizes, of array 1, of the to be sorted entries in array 2 and the size of array in total. Or the guarantee that array 2 can take all, and still the number of to be sorted entries. You need to provide an [mre] to define the interface. Then you can get help with implementin. Consider quoting the whole homework assignment.

Comment: And you should still demonstrate your own efforts. Otherwise ...

Comment: The answer to all "no idea how to start" questions is: "read, find working examples, try, fix, redo". I.e. read some text book or tutorial, find a HelloWorld or sample code, try to change it in small steps towards your goal, test, debug; then try the next iteration. Once you got something and it does not work for the very small change you made away from something working, then it is time to ask a focused question here, according to [ask] and maybe using the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

So you have two sorted arrays, and we assume the second array has extra space allocated to hold the merged array.

Here's what that looks like in memory:

```
array0, length 4
+-------+
|a|b|d|h|
+0-1-2-3+

array1, length 3
+-------------+
|b|c|e| | | | |
+0-1-2-3-4-5-6+
```

The extra space is at the end of `array1`'s storage.

After we have finished merging the arrays, what value will be at index 6 of `array1`? Since index 6 will be the last element in the merged array, it will be the largest element of either input array. Since the input arrays are already sorted, it will be either the last element of `array0` or the last element of `array1`. Let's compare them and copy the larger element to index 6. Since `h` is larger than `e`, we copy `h` to index 6. Since we have now put the last element of `array0` in its final position, we can pretend that `array0` is now length 3.

```
array0, length 3
+-------+
|a|b|d| |
+0-1-2-3+

array1, length 3
+-------------+
|b|c|e| | | |h|
+0-1-2-3-4-5-6+
```

Now we do the same thing again for index 5 of `array1`. We compare the last elements of the (shortened) `array0` and `array1`. Since `e` is larger than `d`, we copy `e` to index 5 and reduce the length of `array1` by 1:

```
array0, length 3
+-------+
|a|b|d| |
+0-1-2-3+

array1, length 2
+-------------+
|b|c| | | |e|h|
+0-1-2-3-4-5-6+
```

Repeat until input arrays have been shortened to length 0, and `array1`'s storage will be filled with the final merged array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code for previous suggestion.
If you know how to make it binary, I would like to here your suggestions.

```
void combineArrays(int sortedArr1[], int size1,
    int sortedArr2[], int size2)
{
    int combinedSizes = size1 + size2;
    if (size1 == 0);
    else if (sortedArr1[size1 - 1] > sortedArr2[size2 - 1])
    {
        sortedArr2[size2+size1-1] = sortedArr1[size1 - 1];
        combineArrays(sortedArr1, size1 - 1, sortedArr2, size2);
    }
    else//sortedArr1[size1 - 1] < sortedArr2[size2 - 1]
    {
        sortedArr2[size2 + size1 - 1] = sortedArr2[size2 - 1];
        combineArrays(sortedArr1, size1, sortedArr2, size2 - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: `combinedSizes` is unused. `if (size1 == 0); else ...` is inelegant.

Comment: What if `size2 == 0` ? `if (sortedArr1[size1 - 1] > sortedArr2[size2 - 1])` would have undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the arrays do not overlap, you can merge the sorted arrays in place starting from the highest index:

```
void mergeArrays(const int * restrict a1, size_t n1,
                 int * restrict a2, size_t n2)
{
    for (size_t k = n1 + n2; n1 > 0;) {
        if (n2 == 0 || a1[n1 - 1] > a2[n2 - 1]) {
            a2[--k] = a1[--n1];
        } else {
            a2[--k] = a2[--n2];
        }
    }
}
```

This can be simplified as:

```
void mergeArrays(const int * restrict a1, size_t n1,
                 int * restrict a2, size_t n2)
{
    for (size_t k = n1 + n2; n1 > 0;)
        a2[--k] = (n2 == 0 || a1[n1 - 1] > a2[n2 - 1]) ? a1[--n1] : a2[--n2];
}
```

If you are required to use recursion, change the loop into a recursive call:

```
void mergeArrays(const int * restrict a1, size_t n1,
                 int * restrict a2, size_t n2)
{
    if (n1 > 0) {
        if (n2 == 0 || a1[n1 - 1] > a2[n2 - 1]) {
            a2[n1 + n2 - 1] = a1[n1 - 1];
            mergeArrays(a1, n1 - 1, a2, n2);
        } else {
            a2[n1 + n2 - 1] = a2[n2 - 1];
            mergeArrays(a1, n1, a2, n2 - 1);
        }
    }
}
```